# Showing nearby places in google map search android

Tags: android, google-maps

[I don't want have different countries search suggestions in my app(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRpYn.png)

[I want to have correct or nearest suggestions in google map app(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNs7M.png)

I have tested with this code

```
autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS)
                .build();  

autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);
```

I want to show nearby places when I am typing in search bar. My problem is when one character was entered in search bar, that character related other country places coming as suggestions, I want it to be very nearest one. In other words the search is much similar like android google maps app.

Comment: Only way to get nearby places need web-service API.This API provides nearest places.It's not free,but developer can use this API upto some limits.

**The API is:** https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/ 

**Documentaion:** https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoCompleteSearch component which doesn't show nearby places. I had achieved by using Google Map web-service API.
 
**Web-API:**
 `maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch (GET)` 
 parameters: key(Your API key),
location(lat+","+lang),
 radius(5000),
sensor(true)
 NOTE: I enabled Google Places API Web Service.

Answer (score 0):

```
AutocompleteFilter filter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES)
            .build();
```

Comment: That is not working.I did it.Thanks for quick response.

Comment: There is one simple solution for it add Bound for the prediction result
for ex.
 Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                    mBounds, mPlaceFilter);

It definitely work.